# Retrieve actions that happened in a date range

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I have searched an answer for this but haven't got an exact solution.

I have a simple application in which I track the items that a person favourites. I create a relationship like so:

```
         [:favorite]
(user) ---------------------> (item)
         timestamp:xxxxxx
```

The user node gets a favorite relationship to the item, and I store the timestamp as a relationship property.

There can be several users favoriting the same item, and also one user can favorite several items. Now, my usecase is to find the items that were favorited in a particular date range, like:

(1) Items favorited in the last 1 hour

(2) Items favorited between 1st Jan 2015 and 15th Jan 2015

(3) Hour-wise split of items favorited on 15th January 2015

I am trying to find out the most optimized way to return these results. I am using Everyman Neo4j for PHP.

My question is how do I index the timestamp property (I believe that would vastly improve performance)?

Also, what would be an optimal way to structure the queries for the three scenarios listed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd model time as a kind of tree or linked list structure in the graph.

But for your use-case,
you can use a relationship-auto-index to index the timestamp property and then query for it: see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html

I think it would make sense to choose a format that is easy to search and sort, like `yyyy-mm-dd-hh`

change your `conf/neo4j.properties` to:

```
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=timestamp
```

but you have to re-index existing data,

start rel=relationship()

and you can query it:

```
start rel = relationship:relationship_auto_index("timestamp:2015-01-*")
match (user)-[rel]->(item)
....
```

or

```
start rel = relationship:relationship_auto_index("timestamp:2015-01-*")
return startNode(rel) as user, endNode(rel) as item
```

Ranges are a not possible with numeric values but with strings.

```
start rel = relationship:relationship_auto_index("timestamp:[2015-01-01-00 TO 2015-02-01-00]")
return startNode(rel) as user, endNode(rel) as item
```

Comment: Great thanks. Could you also suggest a solution to how can I return an hour wise split of favorites? That is, say for 15th Jan 2015, I would like to find the number of favorites received for a particular Item A for every hour in that day, ie between 00:00 and 01:00, 01:00 & 02:00 .... 23:00 & 00:00. Running the query 24 times doesn't look beautiful.

Comment: If I have another relation ( called "cities_visited") having a timestamp property, then how will the auto index distinguish between the timestamp of cities_visited versus favorited relationships? In other words, should I use a different property name for storing timestamp value for a different type of relationship? Is there any performance considerations to keep in mind as we add more properties to the relationship index?